# Link is not working inside div and also font awesome link.Why?

Tags: html, css

In this html code the links are not working. I tried lot of things, but I can't get it.

```html
<div class=""container showHide" style="display:none;" id="app">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="row_1">
    <div class="one" style="text-align:left;">
      <p class="sidetext">The Startup</p>
      Autopilot or otherwise, for more than half a decade Elon has stated his
      <a href="#"><button type="button" class="sidebut">Follow</button> 
    </a>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="two" style="width:10%">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com" title="Twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com" title="Linkedin"><i class="fab  fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: now im curious what 'tried lot of things' you do????

Comment: As you see the link which you have placed inside `<div>` should be in `<head>` tag. And you are hiding the div with `display:none` property

Comment: The extra double quote right in the first line at the opening of class throws everything else off.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the link tag should be inside the head at the beginning of your HTML file. Also in your div style, you have it set to 'display:none'. Remove that as well

To answer your question, the correct way to create a link is as follows:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com">Twitter</a>
```

I recommend using w3schools for learning HTML. Give it a try.

Comment: and the most important, of course it's not appearing because "display:none;"

Comment: dude, it's inside vuejs

Answer (score 0):

you use `style="display:none;"` in first div! `display: none;` is used to hide elements without deleting and recreating them.

remove `style="display:none;"` the link are work